# Group action $\phi: G \times X \rightarrow X$ of group $G$ generated by elements of order $7$ and $11$ on $X$ with $|X|=8$ is not transitive

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions

> Let $G=\langle a,b \rangle$ with $ord(a)=7, ord(b)=11$
>
> $|X|=8$
>
> Show that the group action $$\phi: G \times X \rightarrow X$$ $$(g,x) \mapsto g.x$$  is not
>   transitive

I know that $\phi$ is transitive if and only if there is only one orbit.

I also know that the length of the orbit is equal to $|G/G_x|$, where $G_x$ is the stabilizer of $x$.

I know that the said stabilizer is a subgroup of $G$, and I have read that $|G/G_x|=|G| / |G_x|$, but would that not require $G_x$ to be normal?

Also, what is the order of $G$? Naively I would think it is $77$, but I am not sure whether this be deduced from the order of the two generators? From what I have read the answer is no. 
(The reference was [the word problem for groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups)) Please correct me if I am wrong.

I am struggling with this task because I have no description of what $\phi$ does to $X$ and I am not sure of the order of $G$. If I had the order of $G$, I would have candidates for orders of $G_x$ and thus for the lengths of the orbits. (If the formula for factor groups applies for stabilizers).

Any hints and clarifications to the task are welcome.

Comment: group action is transitive if and only if it has exactly one orbit  (you wrote the opposite)

Comment: One "not" too much, thank you. Will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion here would be to reinterpret the notion of group action. Instead of thinking about it as a map $\phi : G\times X\to X$, think of it as a map $G\to \newcommand\Sym{\operatorname{Sym}}\Sym(X)$. Then since the cardinality of $X$ is 8, we have that the map is $G\to S_8$, which means that $b\mapsto 1$, since the order of $b$ is $11$, which doesn't divide $8!$. Thus the image of $G$ in $S_8$ is either trivial or cyclic of order 7. Neither of which can act transitively.

Comment: This perspective is illuminating. Can this notion of group actions always be applied?

Comment: @B.Swan Yes, it is equivalent to define a group action as either a map $G\times X\to X$ satisfying the usual properties, or as a group homomorphism $G\to \operatorname{Sym}(X)$. At least for normal group actions, where the group isn't a topological group or something.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this, it is so much more comfortable to think in such terms.

Comment: @B.Swan Glad it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

The image of $G$ is a subgroup of $Sym(8)$ which has cardinality $8!$, since $8!$ and $11$ are coprime and the  order of the image of $b$ must divide $8!$ this image  is the neutral element, so the image of $G$ has at most 7 elements